# If select exists, use it. If not, try it on different table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, space-efficiency

I have a piece of code like this:

```
IF  EXISTS(SELECT VALUE
                FROM   tableA
                WHERE  nameid = 'thisName')
BEGIN   
    SELECT distinct VALUE
    FROM   tableA
    WHERE  nameid = 'thisName'
    ORDER BY value
END

ELSE BEGIN     
    SELECT distinct VALUE
    FROM   tableB
    WHERE  nameid = 'thisName'
    ORDER BY value
END
```

Basically select something from `tableA`, if I don't find result there, try it in `tableB`.

Is there a more efficient way how to write this? So I don't have to write select from `tableA` twice (once inside the `EXISTS` statement and once as the actual select).

I was toying with `COALESCE`, but it allows only one result, not a set.

Comment: If this statement is stand-alone, this is as efficient as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
    SELECT distinct VALUE
    FROM   tableA
    WHERE  nameid = 'thisName'
    ORDER BY value
if(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN 
    SELECT distinct VALUE
    FROM   tableB
    WHERE  nameid = 'thisName'
    ORDER BY value
END
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that it returns two selects if the first one is empty. Because I have this in stored procedure and expect only one result, it would cause troubles.

Comment: I didn't want to be ungrateful, standalone it would be fine, but it won't work for my stored procedure.